# GUI will only Work for Newest Towers and I Don't Know Why. (Gamemaker)

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-studio-2, game-maker-language

I have a problem where in a game.  when I make in a place the first tower the GUI works fine, but when I place the second tower the GUI only works for that second tower, and it just goes on and on for each newest tower my place.

Step Event:

```
if placed != false
{
    image_alpha = 1;
    
    if collision_circle(x,y,200,oEnemy,false,true)
    {
        if instance_exists(oEnemy)
        {
            target = instance_nearest(x,y,oEnemy)
            if target.x < x
            {
                direction = point_direction(x-18,y,target.x,target.y);
            }
            else
            {
                direction = point_direction(x+18,y,target.x,target.y);
            }
            if alarm[0] = -1
            {
                alarm[0] = 60;
            }
        }
    }

    if mouse_check_button(mb_any)
    {
        if !position_meeting(mouse_x,mouse_y,self)
        {
            GuiOpen = false;
        }
        else
        {
            GuiOpen = true
        }
    }
}
else
{
    x = mouse_x;
    y = mouse_y;
    image_alpha = 0.5;
}

if GuiOpen = true
{
    instance_create_layer(x,y-65,"Instances2",o_Tower1Upgrade);
}
else
{
    instance_destroy(o_Tower1Upgrade);
    instance_destroy(o_tower1upgradebutton1);
}
```

I tried my best to figure out the bug but i really just can't, theres no errors in the output or anything i could find thats wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `position_meeting` you might wanna try `instance_position`.
The reason for this is because "_meeting" means if any object of that type will fullfill their role, rather than the specific object you want to get.

Source: https://manual.gamemaker.io/monthly/en/GameMaker_Language/GML_Reference/Asset_Management/Instances/instance_position.htm

I based this off a similair experience I had with `place_meeting` and `instance_place`. The problem and solution looks pretty similair:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/158359/when-there-are-multiple-objects-of-the-same-type-how-do-i-know-which-one-i-am-c

Comment: Im not sure if I used the function wrong or I just made a programming error but it did fix the problem I was having earlier, but now the gui wont go away when I click somewhere else, This is the only code i changed: ````if mouse_check_button(mb_any)
{
 if instance_position(x,y,self) != noone
 {
 GuiOpen = true;
 }
 else
 {
 GuiOpen = false;
 }
}````

Comment: The code seem to look fine to me, so you might want to debug that part to see what the `instance_position` actually returns if it's not `noone` by clicking somewhere else. You could set a new var/variable for the instance_position so it'll be easier to see what it returns in that variable. Is it also the intention that it's `mouse_check_button` and not `mouse_check_button_pressed`? The difference between them is that for the former, you need to hold down the mouse button, and the latter registers as a click.

Comment: Well I made it to where when a tower is placed it shows the instance position variable and Gui open variable underneath it, and when I click anywhere away from the tower neither variables change, the instance position variable just showing the ID of the tower no matter what, but the weird thing is when I place a new tower instead of both towers changing the instance position variable or the new tower showing the same variable, they both show there own  ID's. so I dont really know.

Comment: I think this is because this is the Step Event of the Tower, and you want to do an action that's not related to the tower's script. (namely: unselecting it) Maybe you should move the mouse script to a different object. (maybe a persistent object that's always active for general purposes like these?)